# If multiple pages are using the same css file,does it load again and again?

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

This is a general question but i didn't found any satisfactory answer of this.I am creating a website with 7-8 pages.I have a common css which is being used in all the pages.When i go to my homepage this css gets loaded.Now when i go to some other page,would this css get loaded again from server or from browser local cache?
I read somewhere that you have to make some changes in server's .htaccess file for enabling the browser cache.Does browser itself doesn't use the cached files? I would be hosting the website first time so i have no idea of this stuff.Please guide so that i can make a site with better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the caching policy enforced by the web server/ Most goods ones will only deliver it once and that may be over multiple visits to your site. Perhaps look at the HTTP headers to find out. Firebug can do this for you

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the browser settings.  I do notice in chrome I sometimes need to empty the cache. You can also specify it to cache. I am not exactly sure how, but you can look up application caching.

Comment: The server can instructed to cache a file for X days/houts/etc/. Post is not cached but CSS uses Get. Of course a browser can dump stuff and therefore it has to be reloaded. It is best in the development environment to configure the server to instruct that no pages are cached